# Why does this merge sort implementation not work?

Tags: javascript, sorting, mergesort

I implemented merge sort with an auxiliary array for the first time to try and make a visualization using JavaScript. It seems like it should work but it isn't. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

```
const merge = (array, auxArray, start, mid, end) => {
  let k = start; 
  let i = start;
  let j = mid + 1;
  while (i <= mid && j <= end) {
    if (auxArray[i] <= auxArray[j]) {
      array[k++] = auxArray[i++];
    } else {
      array[k++] = auxArray[j++];
    }
  }
  while(i <= mid) {
    array[k++] = auxArray[i++];
  }
  while(j <= end) {
    array[k++] = auxArray[j++];
  }
}


const mergeSortHelper = (array, auxArray, start, end) => {
  if (start === end) {
    return;
  }
  let mid = Math.floor((start + end)/2);
  mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, start, mid);
  mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, mid + 1, end);
  merge(array, auxArray, start, mid, end);
}


const mergeSort = (array) => {
  let auxArray = array.slice();
  mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 0, array.length - 1);
};
```

EDIT: I forgot to include cases where it doesn't work. Here they are:

Input: [4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7]
Output: [4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7]

Input: [6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 2]
Output: [4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2]

Input: [6, 7, 3, 10, 7, 9, 6, 3, 4, 6]
Output: [6, 7, 3, 9, 6, 3, 4, 6, 10, 7]

It gives similar results for arrays of all sizes but seems to give the correct result on arrays of size 2.

I call the `mergeSort` function after initializing an array (say `a`), with `mergeSort(a)` and then check if the array `a` is sorted by logging it to the console. The array is supposed to be sorted but it isn't. Most of the time the array stays the same but sometimes the array is slightly different but not sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that information initially, I've added it now. It is not sorting like expected.

Comment: Consider adding `console.log()` statements to your program so you can observe the program flow.

Comment: I've tried using `console.log()` to log the `start`, `mid`, and `end` values at every recursive call and they seem correct. I've also tried logging the entire list at each recursive call but I can't pinpoint where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case of sorting the array `[4,3,2,1]`

```
let array = [4,3,2,1];
mergeSort(array);
    auxArray = <copy of array>
    mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 0, 3);
        mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 0,1);
            mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 0,0); // returns immediately
            mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 1,1); // returns immediately
            merge(array, auxArray, 0,1);  // arr[0-1] = {3,4}
        mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 2,3);    
            mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 0,0); // returns immediately
            mergeSortHelper(array, auxArray, 1,1); // returns immediately
            merge(array, auxArray, 0,1);  // arr[2-3] = {1,2}
        <at this point arr is [3,4,1,2] and auxArray is still [4,3,2,1]
        merge(array, auxArray, 0,1);  // OOPS, you are remerging the junk in auxArray back into array
```

The problem is that as you are recursing down, you are putting the sorted contents of each 1 or 2 element set into `arr`, but as you recurse back up, you're remerging the unsorted stuff of `auxArray` back into `array`.

The easy fix is to copy the contents of `array` back into `auxArray` at the end of the `merge` function.

```
  ...

  while(j <= end) {
    array[k++] = auxArray[j++];
  }

  // ADD THIS LOOP TO THE END OF YOUR merge FUNCTION
  for (t = 0; t < array.length t++) {
     auxArray[t] = array[t];
  }
}
```

But here's another hint.  Get rid of `auxArray`.  You don't need it.  Or if you do, just declare and use it `merge`